# Simpletest: working with sessions and custom function

Tags: 7, sessions, testing

I need to add a simpletest case to my custom module.

Module functionality:

The module has a function to store data on $_SESSION, on the next page load if $_SESSION has a custom value a javascript code is printed (drupal_add_js: inline) in the bottom of the page.

Test Steps:

1. Function execution that adds some keys on $_SESSION
2. User goes to frontpage.

Something like:

```
public function testCase() {

    // Store session flag.
    my_custom_function_that_stores_session_data();

    // Go to frontpage.
    $this->drupalGet('/');    

    $this->assertRaw('myjscode', 'JS is found');

}
```

This code is not working:

The test do not pass `$this->assertRaw('myjscode', 'JS is found');`, How can I work with sessions in simpletest?

There is no problem to add a custom user if it will be necessary to prevent cache.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: This code is not working and I don't know if this is the right way to work with sessions.

Comment: Could you expand on "not working"? What do you expect it to do, what does it do, what errors do you get, etc? Remember we've never seen this code before nor your module, a bit more information from your side will probably yield a quicker and more accurate answer